# Panorama - horizontal scrolling direction

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I use the panorama in my application. How do I find the horizontal scrolling direction? I need to know the direction - Left to right, or right to left.

Comment: You mean that you want to have a event that triggers once you scroll left, and one that triggers when you scroll right?

Comment: I need to scroll direction. I'm dynamically generating content depending on the direction.

Comment: Can you just use the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectedindex(v=vs.105).aspx) property on the Panorama? If it was 1, but now 2... If it was 0, but now 2...

Comment: Thank you very much. It's simple and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectedindex%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property of the Panorama. Not exactly what you're looking for, but you will be able to know if you went from index 0 to 1.